# Linq sum on object w/o group

Tags: c#, linq

This seems simple enough but I'm not getting it for some reason.

Given:

```
public class Foo
{
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; private set; }
    public Bar Totals { get; private set; }

    public Foo()
    {
        // Blah blah something to populate List of Bars
        this.Bars = new List<Bar>()
        {
            new Bar("Some dude", 50, 1),
            new Bar("Some other dude", 60,25)
        };

        // Calculate Total
        var totals = Bars
            .GroupBy(gb => gb.CustomerName) // When I comment out line i get "Bar does not contain a definition for "Sum" and no extension...."  I want the sum of this without the group.
            .Select(s => new
                {
                    Cost = s.Sum(x => x.Cost),
                    Donation = s.Sum(x => x.Donation),
                }
            ).ToList();

        Totals = new Bar("Totals", totals[0].Cost, totals[0].Donation);

    }

}

public class Bar
{
    public string CustomerName { get; private set; }
    public int Cost { get; private set; }
    public int Donation { get; private set; }
    public int Total { get { return Cost + Donation; } }

    public Bar(string customerName, int cost, int donation)
    {
        this.CustomerName = customerName;
        this.Cost = cost;
        this.Donation = donation;
    }
}
```

I'm having a few problems here:

-This works *with a group by*, but if i take out the group by *which is my end goal* I get "Bar does not contain a definition for "Sum" and no extension....".  I want this sum on the entire collection, so do not want a group by.

-I'm creating an anon object before placing into a Bar because I'm not sure how to create a Bar without a parameterless constructor (and I can't add one to this particular class)

-I don't like accessing the "var totals" data using index 0 - should I not be ToListing at the end? If not, how do i access the properties? totals.Cost does not work.

Please help me figure out the proper way to get around my issue (specifically the 3 bullet points above this paragraph).  Pretty new to the fluent (and linq in general)syntax and I'm trying to figure out the right way to do it.

EDIT:

thanks for the responses all.  Taking kind of a combination of several answers really got me to what my end goal was (but biggest thanks D Stanley)

This is how I'm implementing now:

```
public Foo()
{
    // ....

    // Calculate Total
    Totals = new Bar("Totals", Bars.Sum(s => s.Cost), Bars.Sum(s => s.Donation));
}
```

Guess I was just making it more complicated than it needed to be! :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but if i take out the group by I get "Bar does not contain a definition for "Sum"

That's because when you take out the `GroupBy` you're iterating over the individual items instead of a collection of groups.  If you want to sum the entire collection use

```
var totals = new 
        {
            Cost = Bars.Sum(x => x.Cost),
            Donation = Bars.Sum(x => x.Donation),
        }
    ;
```

or if you want a collection with one item, just change your `GroupBy`:

```
    var totals = Bars
        .GroupBy(gb => true) // trivial grouping
        .Select(s => new Bar
            {
                Cost = s.Sum(x => x.Cost),
                Donation = s.Sum(x => x.Donation),
            }
        ).ToList();
```

> -I'm casting to an anon object before placing into a Bar because I'm not sure how to cast it in without a parameterless constructor (and I can't add one to this particular class)

Just change your projection to

```
var totals = new Bar("Totals", Bars.Sum(x => x.Cost), Bars.Sum(x => x.Donation));
```

> I don't like accessing the "var totals" data using index 0 - should I not be ToListing at the end? If not, how do i access the properties? totals.Cost does not work.

If you take out the group by you end up with just one object.  If you have a colection with one item you could use `First`:

```
Totals = new Bar("Totals", totals.First().Cost, totals.First().Donation);
```

Comment: thanks!  The explanations to go along with the snippets provided really helped me understand the why of uh... why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

The `s` variable in the lambda is of type `Bar` if you remove the `GroupBy`.  You want it to be `List<Bar>` instead in your case.  So, what I think you want is something like:

```
var totalCosts = Bars.Sum(x => x.Cost);
var totalDonations = Bars.Sum(x => x.Donation);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want this sum on the entire collection, so do not want a group by.

Then use `Sum` on the collection

```
 Bars.Sum(x => x.Cost)
```

> I'm casting to an anon object before placing into a Bar because I'm not sure how to cast it in without a parameterless constructor (and I can't add one to this particular class)

You are not casting, you are creating anonymous objects

> I don't like accessing the "var totals" data using index 0 - should I not be ToListing at the end? If not, how do i access the properties? totals.Cost does not work.

If you want single result use `First`.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple enough, when you do `Bars.Select(s =>`, s is of type `Bar` and `Bar` has no definition of `Sum`. If you want the sum of all of it without any grouping, you can do:

```
Bars.Sum(b => b.Cost);
Bars.Sum(b => b.Donation);
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need this :

```
Totals = new Bar("Totals", Bars.Sum(o => o.Cost), Bars.Sum(o => o.Donation));
```

Comment: Ooh Philip that's exactly what I was looking for, though I had already figured it out based on the other answers (and accepted one already) +1 though since this came in pretty much exactly when I did my edit for what I ended up going with! :)